# tic tac toe does not change the player and does not win even if created condition

Tags: python

I was asked to write a simple tic tac toe game in Python.

Currently I'm having two major issues:

1. The player symbol doesn't change from X to O and from O to X (as written in the moveandturn function)
2. Even when I create a winning condition with the first chosen symbol my code does not identify the win.(see win function in code)

It looks ok for me except I'm not sure what should I send to my win function

code:

```
def moveandturn(whoseturn,board):
    rowloc=int(input("Player, insert the deserved row to place your symbol"))
    coloc=int(input("Player, insert the deserved column to place your symbol"))
    if board[rowloc][coloc] =='e':
        board[rowloc][coloc] = whoseturn
    else:
        print("The deserved place is taken")
        rowloc = int(input("Player, insert the deserved row to place your symbol"))
        coloc = int(input("Player, insert the deserved column to place your symbol"))
    for i in range(0,3):
        print(board[i], '\n')
    if whoseturn=='O':
        whoseturn='X'
    if whoseturn=='X':
        whoseturn='O'
    return whoseturn
def win(board,x,y, whoseturn):
    if board[0][y] == (whoseturn) and board[1][y] == (whoseturn) and board [2][y] == (whoseturn):
        return True
    if board[0][y] == (whoseturn) and board[1][y] == (whoseturn) and board [2][y] == (whoseturn):
        return True
    if board[x][0] == (whoseturn) and board[x][1] == (whoseturn) and board [x][2] == (whoseturn):
        return True
    if board[x][0] == (whoseturn) and board[x][1] == (whoseturn) and board [x][2] == (whoseturn):
        return True
    if board[0][0] == (whoseturn) and board[1][1] == (whoseturn) and board [2][2] == (whoseturn):
        return True
    if board[0][0] == (whoseturn) and board[1][1] == (whoseturn) and board [2][2] == (whoseturn):
        return True
    if board[0][2] == (whoseturn) and board[1][1] == (whoseturn) and board [2][0] == (whoseturn):
        return True
    if board[0][2] == (whoseturn) and board[1][1] == (whoseturn) and board [2][0] == (whoseturn):
        return True
    return False
def isfull(board):
    for i in range(0,3):
        for j in range(0,3):
            if board[i][j]=='e':
                return False
    return True
def main():
    board = [['e','e','e']
            ,['e','e','e']
            ,['e','e','e']]
    print("Welcome to the great tic tac toe game!")
    print("Your board is now loading...")
    for i in range(0,3):
        print(board[i],'\n')
    player1=input("Player 1, select your symbol (X/O)")
    if player1 =='O':
        print('X is player 2s symbol')
        player2 = 'X'
    else:
        print('O is player 2s symbol')
        player2 = 'O'
    print("Player 1 will start")
    whoseturn=player1
    while(not (win(board,0,0,whoseturn)) and not isfull(board)):
       whoseturn=moveandturn(whoseturn,board)
       moveandturn(whoseturn,board)
    if not win(board,0,0,whoseturn) and isfull(board):
        print("Tied")
    else:
        print(whoseturn,"wins")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I will be very thankful for any help from you solving the problems listed above!

Comment: When you run this using a debugger, what is the *first* point at which it behaves differently than you expected?

Comment: It does not change the symbole in the third turn. for example if the first chosen symbol is X it lets me place it on the board and than changes to O and lets me place it but does not change back to O after that @ScottHunter

Comment: That does not answer the question I asked.  Have you tried using a debugger?

Comment: Besides the problem with if / elif already mentioned in answers, I think you have a logical error in your code. Code manages a players move, then toggles the player and then check if the player has win (but checks the changed player not the one did the last move). I suggest to reconstruct the code at this point to manage move, check win and toggle player at this order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For 1st problem

> 1. The player symbol doesn't change from X to O and from O to X (as written in the moveandturn function)

In function moveandturn the problem is the conditionals don't work as you expect.

```
if whoseturn=='O':   # 1
    whoseturn='X'
if whoseturn=='X':   # 2
    whoseturn='O'
```

When whoseturn == 'O' is True, whoseturn gets changed to 'X' by 1 above.  Then immediately, whoseturn gets changed back to 'O' by 2 above

Solution is to change above if conditionals to:

```
if whoseturn == 'X':
  whoseturn = 'O'
else:
  whoseturn = 'X'
```

Or more simply:

```
whoseturn = 'X' if whoseturn == 'O' else 'O'
```

**Code Refactoring**

To solve above and the other problems in the code (including 2nd problem)

```
def get_move(whoseturn, board):
  # changed from moveandturn (to make the function do only one thing rather than two unrelated things, which was getting a move and switching turns)

  rowloc=int(input("Player, insert the deserved row to place your symbol: "))
  coloc=int(input("Player, insert the deserved column to place your symbol: "))
  while True:
    if not (0 <= rowloc < 3 and 0 <= coloc < 3):
      print('row and column must be 0, 1, or 2')
    elif  board[rowloc][coloc] !='e':
      print("The deserved place is taken")
    else:
      board[rowloc][coloc] = whoseturn
      break

  return rowloc, coloc

def display_board(board):
  print('\n'.join([' '.join(board[i]) for i in range(3)]))

def win(board, whoseturn, x, y):
  """ using code from https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/24764/tic-tac-toe-victory-check """
  # The posted code had many of the if conditions identical and always called win using row 0 and column 0 which is incorrect

  #check if previous move caused a win on vertical line 
  if board[0][y] == board[1][y] == board [2][y] == whoseturn:
    return True

  #check if previous move caused a win on horizontal line 
  if board[x][0] == board[x][1] == board [x][2] == whoseturn:
    return True

  #check if previous move was on the main diagonal and caused a win
  if x == y and board[0][0] == board[1][1] == board [2][2] == whoseturn:
      return True

  #check if previous move was on the secondary diagonal and caused a win
  if x + y == 2 and board[0][2] == board[1][1] == board [2][0] == whoseturn:
    return True

  return False       

def isfull(board):
    for i in range(0,3):
        for j in range(0,3):
            if board[i][j]=='e':
                return False
    return True

def main():
    board = [['e','e','e']
            ,['e','e','e']
            ,['e','e','e']]
    print("Welcome to the great tic tac toe game!")

    player1=input("Player 1, select your symbol (X/O): ")
    if player1 =='O':
        print('X is player 2s symbol')
        player2 = 'X'
    else:
        print('O is player 2s symbol')
        player2 = 'O'
    print("Player 1 will start")


    whoseturn=player1
    while True:
      # We alternative players, checking for win at each move
      display_board(board)

      rowloc, coloc = get_move(whoseturn, board)
      if win(board,whoseturn, rowloc, coloc):
        print(f'{whoseturn} wins')
        break

      if isfull(board):
        print('Tied')
        break

      # cange turns
      whoseturn = 'X' if whoseturn == 'O' else 'O'


if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()
```

Answer (score 1):

Without looking at the rest of your code:

```
if whoseturn=='O':
    whoseturn='X'
if whoseturn=='X':
    whoseturn='O'
return whoseturn
```

If `whoseturn` was 'O', you change it to 'X'. Then you immediately change it back to 'O' because `whoseturn=='X'` is true. You want the two options to be mutually exclusive. You were thinking of:

```
if whoseturn == 'O':
    whoseturn = 'X'
elif whoseturn == 'X':
    whoseturn = 'O'
return whoseturn
```