# AI tictactoe - future boards and computer moves

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, tic-tac-toe

I was requested to improve my player vs. player tic-tac-toe to an AI tic-tac-toe in which the player plays against the computer:
to do this I need to write two functions:
one that gets the board and the symbol of the current player and returned a list of all possible future boards - each future board is a list that contains two elements: one is the place that the symbol was placed in and the other is the board after placing the symbol - the board after one turn (I am using a nested list board as can be seen in the code below (in which I received help, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59813093/tic-tac-toe-does-not-change-the-player-and-does-not-win-even-if-created-conditio))

The second function I need is a function which does the computers turn - it uses the first function and picks an optimal move in one of the following ways:

1. picks a random move (just for the beginning, if the computer goes first)  and plays it

*OR*

2. if the computer can win in the next turn he picks and plays this option

*AND*

3. if the player can win in the next turn the computer should "block" him.

what I have is a player vs player tic-tac-toe

code:

```
def get_move(whoseturn, board):
  rowloc=int(input(f'{whoseturn},insert the deserved row to place your symbol: '))
  coloc=int(input(f'{whoseturn} insert the deserved column to place your symbol: '))
  while True:
    if not (0 <= rowloc < 3 and 0 <= coloc < 3):
      print('row and column must be 0, 1, or 2')
      rowloc = int(input(f'{whoseturn},insert the deserved row to place your symbol: '))
      coloc = int(input(f'{whoseturn} insert the deserved column to place your symbol: '))
    elif  board[rowloc][coloc] !='e':
      print("The deserved place is taken, choose again ")
      rowloc = int(input(f'{whoseturn},insert the deserved row to place your symbol: '))
      coloc = int(input(f'{whoseturn} insert the deserved column to place your symbol: '))
    else:
      board[rowloc][coloc] = whoseturn
      break

  return rowloc, coloc

def display_board(board):
  print('\n'.join([' '.join(board[i]) for i in range(3)]))

def win(board, whoseturn, x, y):
  if board[0][y] == board[1][y] == board [2][y] == whoseturn:
    return True
  if board[x][0] == board[x][1] == board [x][2] == whoseturn:
    return True
  if x == y and board[0][0] == board[1][1] == board [2][2] == whoseturn:
      return True
  if x + y == 2 and board[0][2] == board[1][1] == board [2][0] == whoseturn:
    return True

  return False

def isfull(board):
    for i in range(0,3):
        for j in range(0,3):
            if board[i][j]=='e':
                return False
    return True

def main():
    board = [['e','e','e']
            ,['e','e','e']
            ,['e','e','e']]
    print("Welcome to the great tic tac toe game!")

    player1=input("Player 1, select your symbol (X/O): ")
    if player1 =='O':
        print('X is player 2s symbol')
        player2 = 'X'
    else:
        print('O is player 2s symbol')
        player2 = 'O'
    print("Player 1 will start")


    whoseturn=player1
    while True:
      display_board(board)

      rowloc, coloc = get_move(whoseturn, board)
      if win(board,whoseturn, rowloc, coloc):
        print(f'{whoseturn} wins!')
        display_board(board)
        break

      if isfull(board):
        print('Tied')
        break
      if whoseturn=='O':
          whoseturn='X'
      else:
          whoseturn='O'


if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()
```

and a start of the future boards function

code:

```
def futuremove(board,whoseturn):
    newboard=copy.deepcopy(board)
    place = []
    copyboard = []
    arrangement=[]
    final=[]
    for i in range(3):
        for j in range(3):
            if newboard[i][j]=='e':
                newboard[i][j]=whoseturn
                if win(newboard,whoseturn,i,j)==True:
                    loctup=[i,j]
                    place.append(loctup)
                    copyboard.append(newboard)
                    arrangement.append(place)
                    arrangement.append(copyboard)
                    final.append(arrangement)
                    print(final)
                else:
                    break
```

please help me get a working player vs. computer tic-tac-toe game!
any help will be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of different ways you can approach it, one fairly simple approach you might take would be to utilize the [Minimax Algorithm](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/minimax-algorithm-in-game-theory-set-1-introduction/)

In a simple example, where your program looks only one turn ahead, after the play makes a move, your AI would generate a board for every possible move it could make, and from those moves, every possible counter move that the player could make.

Now you want to assign a score to each of the AI's possible moves, how you want to define the scoring algorithm is up to you, but it should represent how good or bad a particular game state is for your AI.

The score of each of the AI's potential moves should be equal to the **worst** score of all the player's counter moves, because we want to assume that the player will act in their best interest.

As such you'll be able to determine which of the AI's potential moves puts it in the best chance of winning the game from the current state. I highly recommend reading the attached article for implementation details and a deeper understanding.